# Returns simplify as null

Tags: c#

So, First of all, I'm a beginner, and 6 months of experience in C# at school. I can do it the other way, but I want to know more ways to do stuffs so.. 
And I need help about this. What happens is, when i run the program everything goes okay until private void Add(), some error comes up and says that Simplify is null? Thanks in advance.

```
using System;

namespace test1
{
 class Details
 {
    int NumberSimplify;
    double Solution;

    private void Ask()
    {
        Console.Write("Would you like to Add or Substract (1 - Add, 2 - Substract) -► ");
        int Opt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch(Opt)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("\nHow many numbers would you like to add? -► ");
                NumberSimplify = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                    
                break;

            case 2:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void DisplayResult(double[] Simplify)
    {
        Console.Write("Result from Addition -► ", Add(Simplify));
    }

    private void AddDetails()
    {
        Ask();
        double[] Simplify = new double[NumberSimplify];
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < Simplify.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Number {0} -► ", i + 1);
            Simplify[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }



    private double Add(double[] Simplify)
    {
        AddDetails();
        for (int i = 0; i < Simplify.Length; i++)
        {
            Solution = Simplify[i] + Simplify[i + 1];
        }
        return Solution;
    }


}


class Execute
{
    public static double[] Simplify { get; private set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Details AddOrSub = new Details();
        AddOrSub.DisplayResult(Simplify);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please clarify of which `Simplify` you´re talking? Where exactly do you get `null`?

Comment: You should include the exact error text.

Comment: BTW `AddDetails` is not going to change the same `Simplify` array that is passed into `Add`

Comment: You have a couple of different variables called `Simplify`.  Which one is `null`?  Where do you initialize that one?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < Simplify.Length; i++)
        {
            Solution = Simplify[i] + Simplify[i + 1];
        }` Will give trow an exception as well. It must be Length-1

Comment: Really you don't need the `Simplify` array in `Execute`  Just return the one you create in `AddDetails` back to `Add`.  Also your `Add` method is going to give you an out of range exception because of `Simplify[i+1]`.  If you just want the sum then do `Solution += Simplify[i];` instead.

Comment: Couple of issues in your code.

Comment: `Console.Write("Result from Addition -► ", Add(Simplify));` would not print result at console. Change it to `Console.Write("Result from Addition -► {0} ", Add(Simplify));`

Comment: Simplify probably becomes null from the start since I did not gave it a size, but it changes on the AddDetails() because of NumberSimplify and returns to normal in Add()

Comment: @mmushtaq yes:p im not the sharpest tool in the shed!

Comment: @mmushtaq yes.. but the issue here was the array, still thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @RoJaIt Thanks:)

Comment: Thanks everyone =)

Comment: [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrC9JG) is working .Net Fiddle of your code.

Comment: @mmushtaq thanks, again!

Answer (score 3):

Simplify is indeed null....

```
public static double[] Simplify { get; private set; }
```

You need to initialize arrays... so this should be more like;

```
public static double[] Simplify { get; private set; } = new double[someNumberOfElements]
```

But as pointed out in the comments, you dont even use this initial version of the variable (It is overwritten anyway in your next methods) so consider removing it altogether and re-visiting your control flow...

Comment: The size is asked on the first class, how do I pass it on the second?

Comment: You don't need to... just dont even have that in the Execute class, you don't use it anway...

Comment: If I don't use it, AddOrSub.DisplayResult(Simplify); gives an error, Simplify inside the parentheses is red

Comment: "Doesn't exist in the current context"

Comment: Yes - you can take it out of there too, and out of the method DisplayResult

Comment: Because you don't use it anyway... try follow the flow through and you will see

Comment: But now, in DisplayResult method, it says the same, doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you, it worked now, I simply removed the array and did some adjustments, works fine now!